# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code at closeMenu (main.js:161)

```
// toggle menu fn
    function toggleMenu() {
        if( isMenuOpen ) {
            closeMenu();
        }
        else {
            openMenu();
            isMenuOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Here's my code at openPage (main.js:171)

```
  function openPage(id) {
    var futurePage = id ? document.getElementById(id) : pages[current],
        futureCurrent = pages.indexOf(futurePage),
        stackPagesIdxs = getStackPagesIdxs(futureCurrent);

    // set transforms for the new current page
    futurePage.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';
    futurePage.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';
    futurePage.style.opacity = 1;
```

at HTMLButtonElement.toggleMenu (main.js:132)

```
// toggle menu fn
    function toggleMenu() {
        if( isMenuOpen ) {
            closeMenu();
        }
        else {
            openMenu();
            isMenuOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Console pointing errors on this line `futurePage.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';`

Comment: `futurePage` is probably undefined. Where do you set it?

Comment: You'll probably have to send the entire code. As @cubrr said, check if you declared the variable, and where you declared it (scope)

Comment: I have an error on this line futurePage.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';

Comment: You need to define futurePage with something like **var futurePage = document.getElementById('id_of_element');**

Comment: i edit the question and added the declaration. please see

Comment: what are the values of `id`, `pages` and `current`?

Comment: @Triby is correct, you must get the value of `futurePage` before you can utilise it. Use `getElementById` to acquire if as applicable, or supply more code as to where it appears in the HTML.

Comment: What does `toggleMenu()` have to do with `openPage()`?

Comment: Please edit your question adding all the relevant code (html, css, javascript) to reproduce your issue, other way, we can't help.